# Why is $Z*Z/({xyx^{-1}y} )= 1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I was reading notes on the Fundamental Group and came across the statement $Z*Z/({xyx^{-1}y}) = 1$. Why is this true?

If a quotient group is trivial doesn't it mean that the two factors are isomorphic meaning  $Z*Z \simeq {xyx^{-1}y}$

Link to the notes: http://math.arizona.edu/~glickenstein/math534_1011/vankampen.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misreading the (admittedly rather poor) notation. The statement isn't that $\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z / \langle xyx^{-1} y\rangle$ is the trivial group. (The $xyx^{-1}y = 1$ bit is supposed to invoke the idea that we're setting $xyx^{-1}y$ to one and seeing what we get.)

The author is saying that the fundamental group of the Klein bottle has [presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) $\langle x, y \mid xyx^{-1}y \rangle$, which means that it's the quotient of the free group $F_2$ on two generators $x,y$ by the normal subgroup 'normally generated' by $xyx^{-1}y$; that is, the smallest normal subgroup of $F_2$ containing this word $xyx^{-1}y$.

Comment: Makes much more sense now! But why is $⟨x,y∣xyx^{−1}y⟩ = 1$?

Comment: @Paul: It's not! That's why I called this poor notation. The notation for this presentation is sometimes written as $\langle x, y \mid xyx^{-1}y = 1\rangle$, that is, "it's the group generated by $x$ and $y$ subject to the constraint that $xyx^{-1}y = 1$". In fact, this group is infinite. That the authors of the notes you're reading didn't use brackets makes it hard to read, and prone to this kind of confusion.

Comment: I understand the notation now. Why is $⟨x,y∣xyx^{−1}y⟩=Z*Z$?

Comment: It's not. $\langle x, y \rangle$ is $\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z$ (by definition). $\langle x,y \mid xyx^{-1}y\rangle$ is a quotient of $\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z$ - it's $(\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z)/N$, where $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $\Bbb Z * \Bbb Z$ that contains $xyx^{-1}y$.

Comment: So what he is trying to say is that the fundamental group itself is $⟨x,y∣xyx^{−1}y>$ and not $Z*Z/{⟨x,y∣xyx^{−1}y>}$! Thanks, Mike!

Comment: That's precisely it. (As said before, not the best notation!)